# How to tell if a mouseup is going to be followed by a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there any way to know, in a jQuery `onmouseup` handler, if the event is going to be followed by a `click` event for the same element?

I have an event handler for a menu hyperlink which unbinds itself when the user either clicks on an element or "drops" (as in drag-n-drop) on an element. I want to avoid prematurely unbinding the handler on `mouseup` if a `click` is coming next.

I realize I can track `mousedown` and `mouseup` events myself or otherwise hack up a solution (e.g. wait 50 msecs to see if a click comes soon), but I was hoping to avoid rolling my own implementation if there's something built-in for this purpose.

Comment: So, you're asking if jQuery is able to predict the future?

Comment: :-)  The browser knows whether a mouseup is going to generate a click, so it's not exactly future-prediction, although if the browser doesn't provide a way to access that knowledge then I agree we're in crstyal ball territory.

Comment: But the browser is already providing everything you need. Think of mouse down / mouse up events as "lower level" than click events. If you need fine-tuned control over mouse buttons, use `up` and `down` and write your own timing code. If you want more abstraction and need less control, use `click`. Don't use both at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built-in because it's really specific to your needs. Thus, there would kilometers of code and documentation to maintain if jQuery would handle any combination of clicks, long clicks, moves, etc.

It's also hard to give you a snippet that satisfies your needs, but a setTimeout is usually the first step to take, with something like that :

```
obj.mouseup = function (){
   obj.click = action; // do action 
   setTimeout ( function() {
       obj.click = functionOrigin // after 500 ms, disable the click interception
   }, 500);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use $(selector).data('events') for that

```
$('div').mouseup(function(){
 if($(this).data('events').click){
  console.log('Has a click event handler')
 }
});
```

Comment: +1 for the pointer to find jquery event handlers on an element... had been wondering about that in another project.